# Compilation of a simple function in c on linux

Tags: c, linux, terminal

When compiling on terminal it says:

```
    studente@Linux-Mint-19-SO:~$ gcc -c prova.c
    prova.c:4:16: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
     void gesoo(int &, int &);
            ^
    prova.c: In function ‘main’:
    prova.c:11:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gesoo’ [-Wimplicit-function- 
   declaration]
      gesoo (a, b);
      ^~~
    prova.c: At top level:
    prova.c:17:16: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
     void gesoo(int &a, int &b){
```

The function that should generate this problem is

```
    void gesoo(int &a, int &b){
        int temp;
        temp=a;
        a=b;
        b=temp;
    }
```

That is a simple swap procedure, which gives me no problem when using it on the Dev-C++ IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is valid C++ but not valid C.  C doesn't support pass-by-reference, everything in C is pass-by-value.  To get the same functionality in C, you need to pass pointers by value:

```
void gesoo(int *a, int *b){
    int temp;
    temp = *a;   // The asterisk dereferences the pointer
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

and you'd call it like this:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 4;
gesoo(&a, &b);  // the & means pass the address of that variable
printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);  // prints a = 4, b = 3
```

Note that this will will also work in C++, but using raw pointers in modern C++ isn't considered best practice.